# UITextField и ошибка fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield

Знаю, что на SO много вопросов такого толка, но там все ответы сводятся к тому, что необходимо сделать извлечение опционала через `if let value = opcionalValue { newValue = value }` и тому подобное. У меня проблема заключается не в извлечении опционала, как такового, а в том, что аутлеты типа TextField не инициализируются введенными в соответствующие поля значениями и не принимают новых значений

Имеется View Controller в котором есть два свойства Text Field. Эти свойства по умолчанию уже имеют значения, которые я задал в сториборде. Т.е. эти значения уже не должны быть nil

```
import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var valueFrom: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueTo: UITextField!
```

Мне необходимо передать значения этих полей в другой View Controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let settingsVC = SettingsViewController()

var min = 0
var max = 100

@IBOutlet weak var randomNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var yesOrNo: UILabel!


@IBAction func randomGeneratePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

if let abc = settingsVC.valueFrom.text {
    print(abc)
} else {
    settingsVC.valueFrom.text = "abc"
    let abc = settingsVC.valueFrom?.text
    print(abc)
}
```

Код в функции `randomGeneratePressed` представлен не оригинальный, а для примера. Вот тут на строке `if let abc = settingsVC.valueFrom.text` приложение падает с ошибкой `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Если это строку написать так: `if let abc = settingsVC.valueFrom.?text` с вопросительным знаком, то ошибки не будет, но на выходе я получу nil. Т.е. получается, что свойства из первого View Controller не инициализируются и даже присвоение значения не помогает. Почему так?

Comment: перед присвоением выполните `let vi = settingsVC.view` чтобы заставить приложение загрузить вью. а вообще не самая хорошая архитектура использовать сториборд для хранения модели

Answer (score 2):

Решил свой вопрос при помощи делегирования. Второй вью контроллер, из которого необходимо передавать значения аутлетов Text Field переменным первого вью контроллера, расширил протоколом `SettingsViewControllerDelegate`

```
import UIKit

protocol SettingsViewControllerDelegate {
    func fillThePropertiesWith(valueOne: String, valueTwo: String)
}

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: SettingsViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var valueFrom: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueTo: UITextField!


    @IBAction func sendData(sender: UIButton) {

        // Присваивание введенных значений переменным
        let minimumValue = valueFrom.text
        let maximumValue = valueTo.text
        delegate?.fillThePropertiesWith(minimumValue!, valueTwo: maximumValue!)
    }

}
```

Первый вью контроллер необходимо подписать под протокол и реализовать метод сигвея и метод протокола

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SettingsViewControllerDelegate {

    let randomGeneration = RandomGeneration()

    var min = 0
    var max = 100

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SettingsSegue" {
            let destanationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SettingsViewController
            destanationVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func fillThePropertiesWith(valueOne: String, valueTwo: String) {
        min = Int(valueOne)!
        max = Int(valueTwo)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, settingsVC.valueFrom не создался на момент присваивания. Вьюшка контроллера загружается только по необходимости (при обращении к ней, например, при отображении окна).

Ты можешь перед присваиванием вручную вызвать settingsVC.view() или передать значение через строковую переменную (а ее выведешь на экран во viewWillAppear) или создать textField не в сторибораде, а в методе init контроллера (не очень хорошо, но иногда приходится).

Comment: Я пробовал привязывать SettingsViewController к тому же вью контролллеру, где описан метод randomGeneratePressed. Соответственно в этот же вью контроллер добавлял эти аутлеты. Результат тот же

Comment: привязывать контроллер бесполезно - даже если он есть, у него еще нет valueFrom. Аутлеты это хорошо, но они создаются только тогда, когда контроллер появляется на экране (до этого они nil). Просто обратись к settingsVC.view() перед присваиванием. Это загрузит вью со всеми аутлетами.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду открыть вьюху с настройками в симуляторе и после этого попробовать запустить метод randomGeneratePressed? Если так, то я так делал, принт который я разместил во вьюДидЛоад прогрузился. Но это не помогает. Я и данные изменял вручную в в полях valueFrom и valueTo. Или я вас не правильно понял?

Comment: Да, показать вьюху это как один из вариантов. А как именно не работает? Тоже падает?
Тогда выведи в лог значение settingsVC. Оно пустое или нет? Если пустое, смотри где ты его присваиваешь.

Comment: Да оно пустое. Сейчас сделал два TextField прямо во View Controller в котором обсчитываю рандом и там все работает, как надо. Буду разбираться почему не работает в первом варианте.

Comment: если settingsVC == nil, значит ты его неправильно или не там создал. Попробуй его создавать или грузить из сторибоарта (а потом и использовать valueFrom) перед переходом на settingsVC.

Comment: Валентин, не могли бы вы посмотреть мой код на гитхабе? Я правда не знаю, можно ли тут выкладывать ссылки на гит

Comment: Попробую посмотреть, хотя не уверен что получится помочь - все-таки ты свой код лучше знаешь. А выкладывать тут можно все что угодно.

Comment: Валентин буду премного благодарен, там кода не много, я только начал изучать программирование и это мое первое приложение, которое я пытаюсь сделать с нуля. Вот ссылка https://github.com/LexDeBash/Randomizer.git

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43030/discussion-between--and--).